# C - Record Not Found in File Handling

Tags: c

I have this C code wherein, the problem I meet is that I can not find the records as I wanted, using file handling it always says no results found. What is the correct way to make my system work clearly and display the records?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>


    void loadMenu();
    void addEmployee();
    void searchEmployee();
    bool found = false;
    int choice;

    FILE*myrec;

    char Name[20],Age[20],IDnum[20],search[20];

    void loadMenu(){
    printf("[1]Add Employee\t[2]Search Employee\t[3]Exit\nChoice:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    }


    void addEmployee (){
    char ans;
    do{
    printf("Enter IDnumber:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(IDnum);
    printf("Enter Name:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(Name);
    printf("Enter Age:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(Age);

    myrec = fopen ("record.txt","a+");
    fprintf(myrec,"%s \t %s \t %s \n ",Name,Age,IDnum);
    printf("Record Saved !");
    printf("Do you want to add another record ? Y/N");
    scanf("%s",&ans);
    fclose(myrec);
    }
    while (ans=='Y'||ans=='y');
    }


    void searchEmployee(){

    myrec = fopen("record.txt","a+");
    printf("Enter Employee IDnumber:");
    scanf("%s",&search);
    while(!feof(myrec)){
    fscanf(myrec,"%s %s %s",IDnum,Name,Age);
    if (strcmp(search,IDnum)==0){
    printf("IDnum: %s\n", IDnum);
    printf("Name: %s\n",Name);
    printf("Age :%s\n",Age);
    found = true;
    break;

    }

    }
    if(!found) printf("No results.");
    fclose (myrec);
    }


    int main(){
    bool repeat = false;
    do{
    loadMenu();
    switch(choice){

    case 1:
    addEmployee();
    break;

    case 2:
    searchEmployee();
    break;

    case 3:
    repeat = true;
    break;
    }
    }while(!repeat);

    getch();
    }
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Never call `fflush(stdin)` - it's UB - see man [fflush](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fflush/). Also please format your code properly.

Comment: Compare `scanf("%s", &search)` vs `fscanf(myrec,"%s %s %s",IDnum,Name,Age)`. One of these will not write the result where you expect.

Comment: how can i fix my code using a better syntax?

Comment: @PaulR - how can i do a better syntax formulation? :(

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty wrong.

A few quick ones:

1. Don't check `feof()` *before* trying to read, that's not valid. In fact, never use `feof()`, unless you've already done a read that has failed.
2. Don't open in append (`"a+"`) mode if you only want to *read* from the file. Reading is supported in this mode, but it's still strange.
3. Perhaps you should try re-opening the file instead of keeping it around opened.
4. Always check the return value of I/O functions like `fscan()`. They can fail.

Answer (score 0):

I see several errors:

1. buffer overflow

   char ans;

   scanf("%s",&ans); // if you enter 'Y' then at least 2 characters are written, 'Y' and '\0'

Use a bigger ans buffer : char ans[10];

and then scanf("%s", ans);

1. pointer to pointer

   char search[20]; // search is a pointer to a buffer

   scanf("%s",&search); // you should use scanf("%s", search);

Comment: For the first one: char ans[50]; scanf("%s", ans);